# bxslider doesn't load in bootstrap 3 tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `bxSlider` and `Bootstrap` tabs for a project. I used three sliders in three tabs. The active tab is showing `bxSlider` but when I click on other tabs it doesn't load slider anymore.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <ul class="bxslider-two">
            <li>
                <img src="http://javieryvaleska.cl/tabs/images/img-home.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://javieryvaleska.cl/tabs/images/img-home.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://javieryvaleska.cl/tabs/images/img-home.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://javieryvaleska.cl/tabs/images/img-home.jpg" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
        <ul class="bxslider">
            <li>
                <img src="http://javieryvaleska.cl/tabs/images/img-home.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://javieryvaleska.cl/tabs/images/img-home.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://javieryvaleska.cl/tabs/images/img-home.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://javieryvaleska.cl/tabs/images/img-home.jpg" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

activation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bxslider,.bxslider-two').bxSlider();
});
```

[Sample project](http://jsfiddle.net/zinannadeem/xwx267Lx/6/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to initialize correctly your slider should be visible.  The slider on the first tab works because it is visible when `bxSlider()` is called.  One idea is to wait to initiate until the tab is clicked.  I modified your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwx267Lx/10/) with an example.

**New jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bxslider-two').bxSlider();
});

$('a[href="#profile"]').one('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".tabs-1").click(function() {
    $('#tabs-1 .bx-viewport').css("height","433");  //manuall hight 
    $('#latest_pros .dishes-item').css("width","245"); //manuall width
});

$( ".tabs-2").click(function() {
    $('#tabs-2 .bx-viewport').css("height","433");
    $('#latest_pros .dishes-item').css("width","245");
});

$( ".tabs-3").click(function() {
    $('#tabs-3 .bx-viewport').css("height","433");
    $('#latest_pros .dishes-item').css("width","245");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bxslider-two').bxSlider();
});

$('a[href="#profile"]').one('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```